# manjaro VBox VM and ipv6

Tags: virtualbox, manjaro, ipv6

I have a manjaro 20.1 VM running in a Ubuntu 20.04 host.

On the host, and on two other Ubuntu machines, and on a Ubuntu VM on one of those hosts the following returns a IPv6 address. It is supposed to return the IPv6 address of the client making the request.

```
curl https://api6.ipify.org
```

However on the manjaro VM it returns an IPv4 address.

IPv6 is enabled on the manjaro :

```
cat /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/all/disable_ipv6
0
```

On the manjaro networking is managed by `systemd-networkd` whereas on the Ubuntus networking is managed by `netplan`.

The manjaro reports IPv6 addresses as so :

```
inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
inet6 fd00::nnn..../64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr noprefixroute 
inet6 2001:nnn.../64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr noprefixroute 
inet6 fe80::a00nnn..../64 scope link
```

Comparing this output to the Ubuntus, I expect that the `2001...`  address would be the one returned by the link.

**UPDATE**
I have installed an export of this VM to another host and it works fine there. The issue is isolated to this VM on this LAN.

Comment: Try `ping -6 api6.ipify.org` to see if you get an error message.

Comment: @JohanMyréen `ping -6` hangs for any target. Furthermore, the default `ping` command hangs. I have to specifiy `ip -4` to get any ping response at all. I have since put an export of this VM to another hosst and on that host it works fine.